# how to send data from jsp page to spring controller using ajax

Tags: jquery, spring

In my application I need to send some  String data (email,name,message) from my Jsp page to a Controller where I will do some validation and save in data base.I m usinig Spring Boot . and jquery I think we use ajax , can you please give me an example , So far I tried but didn t work got a 404 error in console :
Controler :

```
    package com.eBenamar;


import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;



import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.eBenamar.Dao.AnnonceDao;
import com.eBenamar.Dao.UserDao;
import com.eBenamar.Entities.Annonce;
import com.eBenamar.Entities.AnnonceAuto;
import com.eBenamar.Entities.Annonceur;
import com.eBenamar.Entities.Auto;
import com.eBenamar.Entities.User;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
// commentaires
// controller
@Controller
public class AnnonceController {
    /*@Autowired  //zyada 
    private AnnonceAutoDao annonceautodao;*/
    /*@Autowired
    private Annonceur annonceur;*/

    private MailSender mailSender;

    private SimpleMailMessage templateMessage;

    @Autowired

        private ServletContext context;
     private Integer lastid;
    @Autowired
    private AnnonceDao annoncedao;
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    /*@Autowired  //zyada
    private AutoInterfaceDao autodao;*/
    Integer NBPAGE=5;
    String DESTINATION="e:\\images\\";
    String DESTINATION1="e:\\temp\\";


 @RequestMapping(value="/cherchetitre",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String cherchetitre(@RequestParam("recherchetitre") String titre ,Model md
        ,@RequestParam("adresse") String ville)
{
    System.out.println("/cherchetitre.. post");
    PageRequest request =
            new PageRequest(1,NBPAGE);
    Page <Annonce> annonces= annoncedao.findByTitreContaining(titre,request);



    md.addAttribute("annonces",annonces);
    return "affiche";

}
@RequestMapping(value="/sendemail1",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public void sendemail(){


    }
   @RequestMapping(value="/sendemail1",method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public void sendemailget(){

}
```

JSP page :

```
<div class="row col-xs-10 col-md-6 form-group">
<!--              <textarea rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea> -->
             <springform:textarea path="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="5"/>
           </div>
            <div class="row">
               <span class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <a class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right" id="sendemail">Envoyer email</a>
               </span>
            </div>
<script>
$('#sendemail').click( function(){
   $.ajax({
          url:'/sendemail1',
          type:"Post",
          dataType:'json',
          contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success : function() {
                     console.log("SUCCESS: ");

                     },
           error : function() {
                     console.log("ERROR: ");

                     },
           done : function() {
                     console.log("DONE");

                     }
   });

});
</script>
```

Error in console :

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8989/sendemail
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 
Remote Address:[::1]:8989
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Content-Language:fr-FR
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 14 Sep 2017 04:33:30 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=B40E408BBC4209D1CECC9336B3AD3EC1
Host:localhost:8989
Origin:http://localhost:8989
Referer:http://localhost:8989/detail/1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

startup logs :

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.1.RELEASE)

2017-09-14 12:48:56.283  INFO 12980 --- [           main] com.eBenamar.Kijiji2Application          : Starting Kijiji2Application on DESKTOP-DRHD9PN with PID 12980 (C:\Users\user\workspace\kijiji2\target\classes started by user in C:\Users\user\workspace\kijiji2)
2017-09-14 12:48:56.288  INFO 12980 --- [           main] com.eBenamar.Kijiji2Application          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-09-14 12:48:56.507  INFO 12980 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5f058f00: startup date [Thu Sep 14 12:48:56 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-14 12:49:00.407  INFO 12980 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$289fc04d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-09-14 12:49:01.713  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8989 (http)
2017-09-14 12:49:01.745  INFO 12980 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-09-14 12:49:01.748  INFO 12980 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
2017-09-14 12:49:02.631  INFO 12980 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2017-09-14 12:49:02.640  INFO 12980 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-09-14 12:49:02.641  INFO 12980 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6139 ms
2017-09-14 12:49:03.193  INFO 12980 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-09-14 12:49:03.198  INFO 12980 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-14 12:49:03.199  INFO 12980 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-14 12:49:03.199  INFO 12980 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-14 12:49:03.199  INFO 12980 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-14 12:49:03.886  INFO 12980 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-09-14 12:49:03.919  INFO 12980 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-09-14 12:49:04.093  INFO 12980 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2017-09-14 12:49:04.095  INFO 12980 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-09-14 12:49:04.101  INFO 12980 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-09-14 12:49:04.185  INFO 12980 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Thu Sep 14 12:49:04 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Thu Sep 14 12:49:05 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Thu Sep 14 12:49:05 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Thu Sep 14 12:49:05 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Thu Sep 14 12:49:05 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Thu Sep 14 12:49:05 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Thu Sep 14 12:49:05 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Thu Sep 14 12:49:05 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Thu Sep 14 12:49:05 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Thu Sep 14 12:49:05 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2017-09-14 12:49:05.342  INFO 12980 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-09-14 12:49:06.544  INFO 12980 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2017-09-14 12:49:07.151  INFO 12980 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-09-14 12:49:07.784  INFO 12980 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-09-14 12:49:08.825  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5f058f00: startup date [Thu Sep 14 12:48:56 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-14 12:49:09.031  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/home]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.index()
2017-09-14 12:49:09.033  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/save],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.add(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.034  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/test1]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.test(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-09-14 12:49:09.034  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/detail/{id}]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.detail(org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.Integer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.text.ParseException,java.io.IOException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.034  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/affiche]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affiche2(org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2017-09-14 12:49:09.034  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/save],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.addget(com.eBenamar.Entities.AnnonceAuto,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
2017-09-14 12:49:09.035  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/imagetemp3],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimagetemp3(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.036  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/imagetemp6],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimagetemp6(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.037  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/affiche///{pagenumber}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affiche1(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-09-14 12:49:09.038  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/images],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimage(java.lang.Integer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.039  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/images5],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimage5(java.lang.Integer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.042  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/imagetemp4],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimagetemp4(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.042  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/imagetemp5],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimagetemp5(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.043  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/images7],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimage7(java.lang.Integer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.043  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/imagetemp7],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimagetemp7(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.043  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/imagetemp8],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimagetemp8(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.044  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/images6],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimage6(java.lang.Integer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.044  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/images2],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimage2(java.lang.Integer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.044  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/imagetemp2],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimagetemp2(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.045  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/imagetemp],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimagetemp(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.053  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/images8],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimage8(java.lang.Integer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.053  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/images3],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimage3(java.lang.Integer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.054  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/images4],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affichimage4(java.lang.Integer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-09-14 12:49:09.054  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/cherchetitre],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.cherchetitre(java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.String)
2017-09-14 12:49:09.054  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/affiche//{selectedcategorie}/{ville}/{pagenumber}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affiche(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2017-09-14 12:49:09.054  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/affiche/{ville}],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affiche(org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2017-09-14 12:49:09.061  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/affiche/{search}/{selectedcategorie}/{ville}/{pagenumber}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.affiche(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2017-09-14 12:49:09.061  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/sendemail1],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.sendemailget()
2017-09-14 12:49:09.062  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/sendemail1],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.sendemail(com.eBenamar.Entities.Annonceur)
2017-09-14 12:49:09.063  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/test/{nb}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.test1(java.lang.Integer)
2017-09-14 12:49:09.068  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-09-14 12:49:09.068  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-09-14 12:49:09.267  INFO 12980 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-09-14 12:49:09.269  INFO 12980 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-09-14 12:49:09.374  INFO 12980 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-09-14 12:49:10.224  INFO 12980 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-09-14 12:49:10.403  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8989 (http)
2017-09-14 12:49:10.411  INFO 12980 --- [           main] com.eBenamar.Kijiji2Application          : Started Kijiji2Application in 15.107 seconds (JVM running for 15.917)
2017-09-14 12:49:17.787  INFO 12980 --- [nio-8989-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-09-14 12:49:17.788  INFO 12980 --- [nio-8989-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-09-14 12:49:17.833  INFO 12980 --- [nio-8989-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 45 ms
```

Comment: Please, add whole controller code. Also, startup logs may be helpful

Comment: I updated with whole controller and startup logs ,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please. Provide your configs. There is something weird. Look at start logs:

```
2017-09-14 12:49:09.061  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/sendemail1],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.sendemailget()
2017-09-14 12:49:09.062  INFO 12980 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/sendemail1],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.eBenamar.AnnonceController.sendemail(com.eBenamar.Entities.Annonceur)
```

You have `/sendemail1` endpoints. Also, other endpoints have other weird numbers. There is a problem with wrong mapping not equal your code

Comment: sorry about that , because I changed sendemail to sendemail1 but didn't update. actually it should be sendemail1 in the mapping and the script . I update

Comment: Ok, could you try change `@Controller` annotation to `@RestController` ?